# ReactJS/Django project: How to handle video uploading/viewing by users?

Tags: django, reactjs, video, youtube, video-streaming

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but I'm building a website/app using ReactJS as frontend and Django REST as backend (may or may not be relevant...), and I'm looking for a way for users to upload videos and view them on my website.
The app is expected to have around 100 users (being able to view the videos), and maybe around 50 hosted videos. This is just a rough indication.

What's generally the way to go? Do you store it locally? Or do you use a video hosting platform? Youtube?

Comment: How is this a **programming** question? It sounds more like a project planning. What do you expect from us? For example you say there is 100 users. Is that 1 video per user?? Do you have a size limits?? Can your server host 100 of these max video sizes?? Does your server have a big bandwidth limit to handle all these multiple downloads? You already know these answers better than us... Maybe just use a hosting platform. Use a site like Google for reviews & recommendations of such a thing.

Comment: I have no clue to be honest. I was looking for suggestions but guess writing a wall of rant was time better spent for you.

Comment: @VC.One I'm assuming you have no interest in genuinely helping me but for the people that do, I have updated my post. I have not decided on hosting yet, it depends on the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the 50 videos would be uploaded by you (or an admin) and that the users of your website won't be able to upload new videos. In this case YouTube could be a good option. I believe it has a 50 video per day upload limit, which should be more than enough for your website. Given the scale of your project, either solution works and it is more of a personal preference in my opinion.

Comment: I've looked into this but I believe every user who wants to uploads videos needs to have their own youtube account and videos will be uploaded there? As opposed to having a single youtube account (mine) which everyone will upload to. I made a question on this earlier but I got no response on it and I couldn't figure it out, so I went the local route.

Comment: You might need to write scripts to encode the uploaded videos to a specific frame rate and sample aspect ratio, for them to render correctly in the browser.